# Offline and security in iOS App

Tags: ios, security, core-data, sqlcipher

I am designing offline features for an app which caches data in offline mode and provides them to users.  The app also needs to support the login feature in the offline mode.

I am seeing Sqlicipher as a better option than [Core data security with File Protection](https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/core-data-and-enterprise-iphone-applications-protecting-your-data/) because only when data protection is enforced in iOS device the security of the data is ensured.

And I am also afraid of the hardware encryption of iOS due to this [incident](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2009/07/iphone-encryption/).

As part of my design for Sqlicipher, I have planned the below staregy:

1. Use SqlCipher for storing the sensitive data.
2. Make the user's credentials as the key for the SqlCipher DB access.
3. Store the credentials of user in keychain access.

Questions:

1. Is storing credentials in keychain access a safer option and foolproof. if not, what is the alternative?
2. Is my understanding on Core data's security in light of data protection correct?

Comment: Will **never** be possible.  If your app has access to a secret,  then an attacker has access to the same secret via a debugger.

Comment: How will the hacker will have access to debugger when the app in running?

Comment: Judging by your profile I can understand it is possible. Any pointers  on how it is done..?